# MySQL: using procedure in view gives known error, but has none of the known symptomes

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view

I got this procedure'get_usage' defined as such:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(SELECT order_id,`usage`, created, expire FROM ',table_name,' )') SEPARATOR '\r\nUNION\r\n'),' ORDER BY created ASC')
    INTO 
        @resultQuery
    FROM 
        information_schema.`TABLES`
    WHERE
        table_name LIKE "usage_%";

    PREPARE stmt FROM @resultQuery;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Which does what it should do.

For more flexibillity I want to capture the output of this procedure in a view:

```
CREATE 
    VIEW `usage_view`AS 
    SELECT get_usage() as usage_table;
```

after which I planned to do things to the 'usage_table' bit..

BUT.. I keep getting 
**[Err] 1305 - FUNCTION backup.get_usage does not exist**

Looking online there's a lot of talk about spaces between function/procedure-names and the parenthesis, which there aren't.. Or procedures that are faulty, which this procedure isn't (ie: I get expected results).. I'm hoping I missed something or other but pretty much stuck..

Any and all help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: Is that a function? The function must return value.

Comment: aaah, crap, I meant procedure, fixed

Comment: Then you cannot use procedures in SELECT queries.

Comment: considering the results I get back when searching for said error I think it should be possible. But I also noticed that the amount of fail is equal to the complexity of the procedure.. Or so it seems..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use result of stored routine in the view, then you need to create and fill additional table. Create and populate table in the procedure. After, call this procedure, it will create table, then select data from your view.

If you just want to read result-set in the appication, then you can execute SELECT query in the procedure (your procedure does it currently), and read data-set in code (c#, php with mysqli extension, or etc..)